# The generalized Laguerre polynomials: Are there any expressions valid for any case?

Tags: special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

There are general expressions of the generalized Laguerre polynomials.

For example:
$$
L_n^{(\alpha)}(x) = {}_{n+\alpha}\mathrm{C}_n\ {}_1F_1(-n, \alpha+1, x),
\hspace{20pt}(1)
$$
$$
L_n^{(\alpha)}(x) = \sum_{l=0}^n(-1)^l\ {}_{n+\alpha}\mathrm{C}_{n-l}
\frac{x^l}{l!}.
\hspace{35pt}(2)
$$

On one hand, Eq(1) is invalid if $\alpha + 1$ is a negative integer due to a property of ${}_1F_1$, and Eq(2) is also invalid if $n + \alpha$ is an negative integer.

On the other hand, the expressions of $L_n^{(\alpha)}$ for each $n$ is, for example,
$$
L_0^{(\alpha)}(x) = 1,\\
L_1^{(\alpha)}(x) = -x + \alpha + 1,\\
L_2^{(\alpha)}(x) = \frac{x^2}{2} - (\alpha + 2)x + \frac{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2)}{2},\\
L_3^{(\alpha)}(x) = -\frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{(\alpha+3)x^2}{2} - \frac{(\alpha+3)(\alpha+2)x}{2} + \frac{(\alpha+3)(\alpha+2)(\alpha+1)}{6}
$$
([from wikipedia: Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials)).
But in these expressions, $\alpha$ can be any real values, which include the invalid cases for Eq(1) and (2).

So I have the question described in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, using the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)
$$
(z)_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (z-k)
$$
you can write
$$
L_n^{(\alpha)}(x)=\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-n)_k (k+\alpha+1)_{n-k}}{k!}x^k
$$
which is valid for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and all nonnegative integer $n$.

Comment: I tested in the case of $L_2^{(\alpha)}$, and found we should use the rising factorial

Comment: What about negative integers $n$? Is there any expression that is valid?